# ¿Donde debo definir las constantes globales en Cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, constantes

Actualtmente las tengo definidas en el archivo paths.php pero no las recibe bien, ¿Debo ponerlas en otro archivo o tengo que añadir algo en alguna parte?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] (y ganarás tu primera medalla!) y que revises [ask]. La pregunta que haces parece que puede resolverse con una simple búsqueda en google. Yo lo hice y al parecer [el lugar correcto es `config/Bootstrap.php`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37762119/579895)

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias alternativas:

- Definirlas en bootstrap.php [Bootstraping Cakephp](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp)
- Crearte un configurador en el cual defines ciertos parámetros (mi preferida) [aquí](https://securityblog.gr/1957/create-custom-configuration-files-in-cakephp-3/) te explican cómo hacerlo.

Un saludo y espero que te sea de utilidad.